# Correctly updating tray icon after DPI change

Tags: windows, winapi

I have some standard code for creating a tray icon:

```cpp
NOTIFYICONDATA data;
// ...
data.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(inst, L"name", IMAGE_ICON,
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
// ...
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &data);
```

The problem is, when the taskbar DPI changes, the icon becomes upscaled and ugly, like this:

[image: screenshot]

Tips on the Internet suggest using `WM_DPICHANGED`, but I'm afraid that it won't work if my window is in a different monitor than the taskbar. From the docs:

> Sent when the effective dots per inch (dpi) for a window has changed. The DPI is the scale factor for a window. There are multiple events that can cause the DPI to change. The following list indicates the possible causes for the change in DPI.
>
> - The window is moved to a new monitor that has a different DPI.
> - The DPI of the monitor hosting the window changes.

That implies that if the main monitor's DPI changes, but my window is on a different monitor, it won't get this message. I can create another, hidden window, but not only it's ugly by itself, I will also have to keep it on the main monitor even if it changes. I can do polling with a timer, but it's ugly too.

Is there a recommended solution that always works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Microsoft's [Taskbar Creation Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar#taskbar-creation-notification) documentation (emphasis added):

> With Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.0 and later, the Shell notifies applications that the taskbar has been created. When the taskbar is created, it registers a message with the TaskbarCreated string and then broadcasts this message to all top-level windows. **When your taskbar application receives this message, it should assume that any taskbar icons it added have been removed and add them again.** This feature generally applies only to services that are already running when the Shell launches. The following example shows a very simplified method for handling this case.
>
> **On Windows 10, the taskbar also broadcasts this message when the DPI of the primary display changes.**

Also, per the [`NOTIFYICONDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataw) documentation, you should be storing multiple sizes in your icon resource and then use [`LoadIconMetric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-loadiconmetric) to load an `HICON` that is appropriate for the current DPI:

> `hIcon`
>
> Type: `HICON`
>
> A handle to the icon to be added, modified, or deleted. Windows XP and later support icons of up to 32 BPP.
>
> If only a 16x16 pixel icon is provided, it is scaled to a larger size in a system set to a high dpi value. This can lead to an unattractive result. It is recommended that you provide both a 16x16 pixel icon and a 32x32 icon in your resource file. **Use [`LoadIconMetric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-loadiconmetric) to ensure that the correct icon is loaded and scaled appropriately.** See Remarks for a code example.

Though, [`LoadIconWithScaleDown()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-loadiconwithscaledown) would probably make more sense to use:

> Loads an icon. If the icon is not a standard size, this function scales down a larger image instead of scaling up a smaller image.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it soon, then accept it. The quote about `TaskbarCreated` is great, that's what I looked for. Regarding `LoadIconMetric`, it calls `GetSystemMetrics` internally, and "This API is not DPI aware" per docs. I'll look into calling `GetSystemMetricsForDPI` and `LoadIconWithScaleDown` manually.

Comment: Finally tested it. Sadly it doesn't work. I see that the issue started with Win11 22H2. Source code and videos here: https://github.com/justanotheranonymoususer/blurry-tray-icons-test. Unfortunately I can't accept the answer. I'm not sure if it's a Windows bug.

Comment: Actually, I found out that if I run both `NIM_ADD` and `NIM_MODIFY` on `TaskbarCreated`, then the icon is updated. I found a solution, and this answer helped, thanks.